# Model updates but Angular Ui does not Rerender even with Ngzone

Tags: angular

I have a requirement where from an external input field outside Angular I am getting input values, using which I am triggering a service in my Angular module which gets relevant data from the back-end. Subscribe function is working fine for internal changes but since here the input values are coming from global function, the UI is not getting rendered.

I have tried `zone.run`, `detectChange`, and `detectCheck` but nothing seems to be updating the UI. The UI is supposed to display the list of items using the `suggestedItems` array. Please let me know what's wrong.

```
    import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { BackendApiService } from '../services/backend-api.service';
    import { WindowAccessService } from '../services/window-access.service';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-search-suggestion',
      templateUrl: './search-suggestion.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./search-suggestion.component.scss']
    })
    export class SearchSuggestionComponent implements OnInit {
      suggestionHeaders = ['Item', 'Item name', 'Item category', 'Item details'];
      suggestedItems; dummyRequestObj; value;

      calledFromOutside(newValue: String) {
        this.zone.run(() => {
        this.value = newValue;
        this.dummyRequestObj.conditions = [];
        this.dummyRequestObj.conditions.push({
                        'column': 'SEARCH_BY_NAME',
                        'value': this.value
                        });
          // this.chngDt.detectChanges();
        this.items.getData(this.dummyRequestObj, false, false);
        console.log(this.value);
      });
      }
      // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
      constructor( public items: BackendApiService, private zone: NgZone, public refWin: WindowAccessService, private chngDt: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.suggestedItems = new Array<any>();
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.items.updateItemList.subscribe(
          (data) => {
            console.log('was triggered');
            this.zone.run(() => {
            this.suggestedItems = data;
            });
            // this.chngDt.markForCheck();
            console.log('data', this.suggestedItems);
          }
        );
        this.refWin.nativeWindow.angularComponentRef = {
          zone: this.zone,
          componentFn: (value) => this.calledFromOutside(value),
          component: this
        };
        this.dummyRequestObj = {
                    "preciseSearch": false,
                    "useFuzzy": false,
                    "mode": 0,
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "noOfRecords": 12,
                    "ascending": false
    };
    }
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th  *ngFor="let header of suggestionHeaders">{{header}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of suggestedItems">
                <td>{{item.erpPartNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{item.itemShortDesc}}</td>
                <td>{{item.productCategoryName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.itemDesc}}</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you please format your code? It is hard to read

Comment: Can you also share your template / HTML code, and the output of `console.log('data', this.suggestedItems);` please?

Comment: added the template in the above code as well for clearity and yes the console.log is showing the updated view of 'this.suggestedItems'

Answer (score 0):

Please add an ngOnChanges() block with the appropriate console.logging for the variable you are interested reacting to changes on. We can go for there. Most likely you will find:

- The variable is not being updated
- The variable is getting reset to a default state
- Alternatively the change detection strategy is not setup as you've expected

You will need to add the hook to your class definition for OnChanges to fire properly:

```
export class SearchSuggestionComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
```

**Update:** I added your code to a plunkr and mocked out your service call. It seems you may have better luck if you move the code that populates suggestedItems into your ngOnInit:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let header of suggestionHeaders">{{header}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of suggestedItems">
          <td>{{item.erpPartNumber}}</td>
          <td>{{item.itemShortDesc}}</td>
          <td>{{item.productCategoryName}}</td>
          <td>{{item.itemDesc}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  suggestionHeaders = ['Item', 'Item name', 'Item category', 'Item details'];
  suggestedItems; dummyRequestObj; dummyResponseObj; value; items;

  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  constructor( ) {
    this.suggestedItems = new Array<any>();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dummyResponseObj =  [ {'erpPartNumber': 'dadd', 'itemShortDesc': 'Mobile', 'itemDesc': 'LG Mobile',
      'productCategoryCode': '42', 'productCategoryName': 'Prisoners defense services', 'uom': 'EA'},
      {'erpPartNumber': 'data 2', 'itemShortDesc': 'Mobile', 'itemDesc': 'LG Mobile',
        'productCategoryCode': '323', 'productCategoryName': 'Prisoners defense services', 'uom': 'EA'}];

    this.items = this.dummyResponseObj;
    this.suggestedItems = this.dummyResponseObj;
         }
}
```

Basically you are trying to hydrate this variable too soon. You need to update the object in OnInit to ensure Angular is ready to go, the template gets bound in time to the component code, and change detection is operational. Many times work done prior to ngOnInit will cause template issues as Angular is not fully spun up yet.

Hope this helps!
*cheers*

Comment: added following code:  ngOnChanges() {
  console.log('the on changes life cycle value of suggestedItems array :', this.suggestedItems);
}, however i found that this is not getting triggered

Comment: did you add the "hook" to your class definition? I added it to my previous answer, please add the hook, then the public function (including console logging). Keep us posted.

Comment: Yes i did that implements OnChanges

Comment: Please let's level-set here.. Are you saying that ngOnChanges never gets called? Please add this code to a plunkr or something. I would be glad to assist. Also is that HTML you have in the bottom of your snippet in the template file or is it actually inside of the component.ts file?

Comment: Yes it  is not getting called

Comment: If my ngOnChanges is not getting called, it means my model is not getting updated but the console shows the values are populating

Comment: Is using angulars "home zone" and leaving the default change detection strategy an option? If so I'd say lets start there, it's possible the user defined zone is not mapping properly with your component/template. Have you tried making zone public (in the constructor injection step) ensuring the template has access to it?

Comment: Also please share the structure for suggestedItems that is output in your console.log located in ngOnInit.

Comment: Thts a nice catch, i will make it public n try once and update

Comment: suggestedItems  is as below: [ {"erpPartNumber":"dadd","itemShortDesc":"Mobile","itemDesc": "LG Mobile","productCategoryCode": "42","productCategoryName": "Prisoners defense services","uom": "EA",},{"erpPartNumber":"data 2","itemShortDesc":"Mobile","itemDesc": "LG Mobile","productCategoryCode": "323","productCategoryName": "Prisoners defense services","uom": "EA",}]

Comment: Making it public did not change anything

Comment: I have updated the issue since i figured out even the model is not updating even inside the subscribe method i am using below code :this.zone.run(() => {
        this.suggestedItems = data;});

Comment: This line:
<th  *ngFor="let header of suggestionHeaders">{{header}</th> is missing the double interpolation bracket. should be {{header}}. If this is not a copy/paste issue, it could cause the template compilation to breakdown entirely.

Comment: Thats copy paste issue, my template has it

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Turns out the code that populates your suggestedItems needs to move to OnInit.

Comment: Also unless you absolutely need it for something else in this component, I would still recommend running inside of the home zone, and using the default change detection strategy (i.e. remove these providers from your constructor).

Comment: this.suggestedItems = this.suggestedItems; I added this in ngOnInit, did not help,

Comment: Did you remove the extra zone and change detection code? I verified the snippet I included will update your display with the response data you shared. If you did in fact remove the zone and change detection code the only other thing it could be would be the service call, however you've indicated that appears to be working based on your review of the console log output.

Comment: when i am console logging this, i can see that this.suggestedItems  is having the updated value, I think the only issue is with NgZone not working

Comment: Which extra zone, i will remove changedetection and other dependencies and update

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use the Angular home zone? i.e don't specify a custom zone and just do what your doing without the custom zone. This is basically what I have done and it works, the only difference is that I don't have a service to hook up to so I had to mock the data in the snippet I shared with you. Be sure to remove the ngZone also. Basically the only constructor injection you should have is for your BackendApiService.

Comment: the zone i have added so that the outside changes updates my model, my requirement is such that an input field values from outside angular app calls a service inside my angular app and updates the angular dom

Comment: Home zone should work for this scenario also... However you could pass the value from the outside control via an @Input attribute on your component.

Comment: Can not go with that approach coz I have to trigger the module as well, that will not be right way of implementing i guess

Comment: I have tried removing zone and other dependencies from everywhere but still no difference in the output, same as before

Comment: Issue fixed, jsp tag issue

Comment: Great news! Sorry I wasn't more help to you, but I'm glad you got it figured out. Please update with your fix, incase other encounter something similar.